# How can I call 'super' from 'define_method'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, remote-debugging, test-environments

I'm trying to prepend a `binding.remote_pry` to all methods from all classes of my application for a test environment.

I try this:

```
classes = []
ObjectSpace.each_object { |o| classes << o if o.class == Class }
classes.each do |classe|
    classe.methods.each do |method_name|
        classe.class_eval do
            define_method(method_name.to_sym) do
                @@bindings ||= []
                @@bindings << Thread.new {binding.remote_pry}
                super
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But I don't know how to call the `super` of each method inside `define_method`
Am I trying to do something too much crazy here?
There is another way? Thanks in advance

Comment: Definitely something crazy. What's the problem with calling `super`, again?

Comment: FYI: `classes = ObjectSpace.each_object.select { |o| o.class == Class }`

Comment: RuntimeError: implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method() is not supported. Specify all arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Cassiano See the linked duplicate. It outlines many ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will search harder next time.

Answer (score -1):

You should call it with explicit empty argument list, otherwise `super` tries to pass arguments from original method, which does not work with methods defined by `define_method`. Just do:

```
super()
```

and you should be fine ;)

Comment: You missed the point, `super` cannot help here. That isn't how you invoke a method you're overwriting.

Comment: Well, it answers question "How can I call 'super' from 'define_method'?" so I don't see how it's missing the point. OP would get another error which will steer him at the direction of how to accomplish his goal. but of course suit yourself with a downvote.

Comment: You're not helping, if you give people advice that points them in the wrong direction without actually explaining why the attempted approach won't work. Please don't add answers if you have no faith that it will actually solve the problem.